# NSFetchedResultsController for fetching date from coredata and display the date in titleForHeaderInSection of UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, core-data

I am storing a string input from textfield and its created dateandtime. I am storing date values in coredata with key `messageDate` which is a string data type. I am converting my date values to string and storing it in coredata.I am able to see the array of stored date and text values like below

```
timeAndDateMsgArr (
    "2016-11-02 17:59 PM",
    "2016-11-02 18:08 PM",
    "2016-11-02 18:08 PM"
)

textArr (
        "Hai",
        "The",
        "I'm"
    )
```

I am able to see the stored text and its created date in `UITableView` by adding two labels in CustomCell. But i need to group the text by date. I have already tried many solutions and below is one of them

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"msgHistory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"messageDate" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

     NSLog(@"fetchcontroller %@",_fetchedResultsController);

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *rawDateStr = [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
    NSLog(@"raw %@",rawDateStr); //****** i am getting null value here************//
    // Convert rawDateStr string to NSDate...
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:rawDateStr];

    // Convert NSDate to format we want...
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
    NSString *formattedDateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    return formattedDateStr;
}
```

Posting a pic to get some idea,current output is like
[image]

My expected output will be something like below, where i will show date in place of month
[image]

But i need to show messages group by date. I have tried apple sample code which suits my requirement where the date key is stored in date data type but in my case i am storing date in string data type. In my case i cannot change the data type because it effects the code. Is their any alternative solution or i need to change the data type? Any help will be really appreciated.

Apple sample code reference link 
[REF LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939)

Answer (score 0):

You can cleanly solve this by adding a non-optional, non-transient, String -messageDateSectionId attribute to your Core Data entity.

Have this -sectionId attribute be derived from the main -messageDate attribute; whenever you set -messageDate, also set -messageDateSectionId to your custom format.

Thus, you will be saving this derived -sectionId attribute along with your main attribute.

Next, when you create the -fetchController, set -sectionNameKeyPath to your -sectionId attribute. Everything in January 1-31, 2013 will have the same -sectionId, and so will be grouped together in the table.

For the -titleForHeaderInSection, you can simply return the -fetchController.sections[SECTION_NUMBER].name value to show your -sectionId string.